# How to find the highest data-attribute with js/jquery and append a div to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you append a div to the div with the highest data attribute data-number?

```
$( ".item" ).append( $( "<div class='highest'></div>" ) );

<div id="container">
    <div class="item" data-number="13"></div>
    <div class="item" data-number="22"></div>
    <div class="item" data-number="142"></div>
    <div class="item" data-number="2"></div>
    <div class="item" data-number="44"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: By looping through all of the divs and testing the `data-number` to get the index of the highest one, then append to that one?

Comment: Are these attributes value unique? What behaviour do you expect if maximum is equal to other one(s)?

Comment: There can be duplicates, in that case all of them should have the div appended

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L79kr1w4/2/)

```
var num = $(".item").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('number');
}).get();//get all data values in an array

var highest = Math.max.apply(Math, num);//find the highest value from them
$('.item').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('number') == highest;//return the highest div
}).append( $( "<div class='highest'></div>" ));//append to that div
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to my own. Though as @A.Wolff stated in a now-deleted comment, you don't need `parseInt()` because the jQuery `.data()` method will automatically return numbers.

Answer (score 6):

If there can be duplicates then I'd say the simplest method is to loop through the divs twice. The first time you figure out what the highest `data-number` is, and then the second time you append to any that have that number:

```
var highestNum = -1;

$("#container .item").each(function(){
    var num = +this.getAttribute("data-number") ;
    if (num > highestNum) 
        highestNum = num;
}).each(function(){
    if (highestNum === +this.getAttribute("data-number") )
        $(this).append("<div class='highest'></div>");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/358njnnx/1/

Comment: What if we need the lowest value instead of the highest?

Comment: Then you change `highestNum` to `lowestNum`, initialise it to `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` instead of `-1` (I probably should've used `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` in my answer in the first place), and change the `<` comparison to `>`. Or in the accepted answer use `Math.min()` instead of `Math.max()`.